# Sign In button always visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

I would like to create a login page but I have a problem with it. I would like the Sign In button to be always visible even if the soft keyboard is visible. Please see the attached images.
[image]

This is a normal login page. I use `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout` and an extended height `Toolbar`.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot the page is scrollable. I have a `NestedScrollView` and I use the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`.

[image]

The problem is that if the soft keyboard is opened then the Sign In button is hidden. I would like the Sign In button to be at the top of the keyboard. I've played with the `isScrollContainer` and `windowSoftInputMode` settings but I could not set the desired behavior.

Here is my xml content if it helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="196dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:minHeight="48dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|end">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity android:name=".activities.authentication.SignInActivity"
        android:theme="@style/RegistrationTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:label="Sign In" />
```

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

My device is an *HTC Sensation* with *Android 5.0.2 (CyanogenMod 12)*

Comment: In your `manifest.xml` try to add this code : `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. I already tried adjustResize and adjustPan but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the correct way to solve the problem.

1. Instead of the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` I used the `android:isScrollContainer="true"` for the `CoordinatorLayout` which basically is the same.
2. `CoordinatorLayout` is a `FrameLayout` where we can align the things more easily with the `android:layout_gravity` attribute.
3. The last and the most tricky part was solving the scroll problem when the soft-keyboard is visible. For this I had to override the `AppBarLayout`'s `Behavior`. The default `Behavior` checks if the scrolling view is big enough to scroll. But that was false if the keyboard was opened. So I modify it to return always true. In this way the scroll works even if the keyboard is visible.

My custom `Behavior`

```
public class MyBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {

    public MyBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout parent, AppBarLayout child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        super.onStartNestedScroll(parent, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the layout xml you can set the custom `layout_behavior` for the `AppBarLayout`

```
app:layout_behavior="com.your.package.MyBehavior"
```

The full content of the layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:isScrollContainer="true">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="56dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:minHeight="48dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="168dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_behavior="com.your.package.MyBehavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In this way everything works as expected. You have a scrollable page where the Sign In button (or footer) is always visible.

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml find your activity and add attribute for keyboardInputMode:
it can look's like

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Must help you

UPD: test result 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. I already tried adjustResize and adjustPan but it didn't help. This new CoordinatorLayout is tricky.

Comment: Look through update& add your <include> code, may be you have some issue there

Comment: Hmm ... not bad. Do you use CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout? Can you please attach your xml code?

Comment: Is your content scrollable?

Comment: Attached the other xml file content as well. You can check it. It is a simple RelativeLayout.

Comment: "Is your content scrollable?" - yes, it's scrollable

Comment: It work for me with your include (but i inject code to container directly without <include>ing). Moreover, try change include content to wrap content, and tell me please what is yours testing device

Comment: Now I've updated the source code. I have a HTC Sensation with Android 5.0.2. Please check it. Now I observed that if the keyboard is hidden then the scroll works as expected but if the keyboard is visible then no scroll and no Sign In button.